# Executing code before .NET's Main() method

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Is it possible to execute any user-provided code before the .NET [Main method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

It would be acceptable if the code had to be unmanaged.

The reason for asking is that this might be a way to solve the problem of calling SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID before any UI elements are displayed (as mentioned in [Grouping separate processes in the Windows Taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924264/grouping-separate-processes-in-the-windows-taskbar))

Comment: Are you actually interested in a C++ answer?

Comment: Sure, if that solves the problem! I'm not afraid of C++ if that's what you're asking :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C# you can add a static constructor to the class which contains the `main` method.  The code in the static constructor will be executed before `main`.

Comment: That certainly does execute before Main, though it doesn't seem resolve the issue of calling SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID. Maybe the problem is it's a Console app

Comment: Yes, changing to a Windows app instead of Console solved my other problem.

Answer (score 2):

A static constructor will execute before Main, but only if the class is actually being referenced by something. Eg:

```
class ClassWStaticCon
{
    static ClassWStaticCon()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}

...
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello main.");
}
```

Will print:

> Hello main.

```
class ClassWStaticCon
{
    public static int SomeField;
    static ClassWStaticCon()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}

...
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassWStaticCon.SomeField = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Hello main.");
}
```

Will print:

> Hello world! Hello main.

If you want to control the order of execution then use a Queue of Action delegates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx in a single static 'initialize all pre main stuff' class.